# Boot broken on an Oracle VPS with msg "Gave up waiting for root file system device" & empty fstab

Tags: boot, initramfs, vps, oracle

I'm using a free-tier Oracle VPS running Ubuntu and it seems like booting no longer works. I don't have physical access to the machine so I can't really try out solutions that ask for a reboot while holding down some key.

```bash
Gave up waiting for root file system device.  Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT!  UUID=8ea5e871-d077-4bfc-9a3a-35f020798df1 does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!


BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.4) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

I ran some additional commands for more info on the situation:

```bash
(initramfs) cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-1036-oracle root=UUID=8ea5e871-d077-4bfc-9a3a-35f020798df1 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 nvme.shutdown_timeout=10 libiscsi.debug_libiscsi_eh=1 crash_kexec_post_notifiers
(initramfs) blkid
(initramfs) ls /dev
vga_arbiter      tty21            tty60            ttyS31
rfkill           tty22            tty61            ttyprintk
mem              tty23            tty62            hpet
null             tty24            tty63            hwrng
port             tty25            snapshot         loop-control
zero             tty26            ecryptfs         loop0
full             tty27            fuse             loop1
random           tty28            ptmx             loop2
urandom          tty29            ttyS0            loop3
kmsg             tty30            ttyS1            loop4
tty              tty31            ttyS2            loop5
console          tty32            ttyS3            loop6
tty0             tty33            ttyS4            loop7
vcs              tty34            ttyS5            dma_heap
vcsu             tty35            ttyS6            udmabuf
vcsa             tty36            ttyS7            net
vcs1             tty37            ttyS8            ppp
vcsu1            tty38            ttyS9            vfio
vcsa1            tty39            ttyS10           bus
tty1             tty40            ttyS11           input
tty2             tty41            ttyS12           psaux
tty3             tty42            ttyS13           uinput
tty4             tty43            ttyS14           rtc0
tty5             tty44            ttyS15           mapper
tty6             tty45            ttyS16           fb0
tty7             tty46            ttyS17           mcelog
tty8             tty47            ttyS18           cpu_dma_latency
tty9             tty48            ttyS19           pts
tty10            tty49            ttyS20           core
tty11            tty50            ttyS21           fd
tty12            tty51            ttyS22           stdin
tty13            tty52            ttyS23           stdout
tty14            tty53            ttyS24           stderr
tty15            tty54            ttyS25           char
tty16            tty55            ttyS26           rtc
tty17            tty56            ttyS27           block
tty18            tty57            ttyS28
tty19            tty58            ttyS29
tty20            tty59            ttyS30
(initramfs) cat /etc/fstab
(initramfs)
```

Do I just need to fill out the fstab? Is it that my server can't see the boot volume at all? How can I get a successful boot?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that your filesystem is corrupted in some capacity or no longer exists as the system is unable to boot past the kernel with an error stating that the filesystem is not found.

It is also possible that your fstab file no longer points to the filesystem, and that needs to be repaired.

Because you don’t have access via Oracle to change any of the files without a working system afaik, I'm afraid you will have to reset the instance.